# ASP.Net Core Web API and persistent basic authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, basic-authentication

I am developing some Web API and for authentication, I used basic authentication for security and implemented a class called `BasicAuthenticationHandler` which inherits from `AuthenticationHandler<TOptions>` as below:

```
namespace WebApi.Helpers
{
    public class BasicAuthenticationHandler : AuthenticationHandler<AuthenticationSchemeOptions>
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public BasicAuthenticationHandler(
            IOptionsMonitor<AuthenticationSchemeOptions> options,
            ILoggerFactory logger,
            UrlEncoder encoder,
            ISystemClock clock,
            IUserService userService)
            : base(options, logger, encoder, clock)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        protected override async Task<AuthenticateResult> HandleAuthenticateAsync()
        {
            if (!Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization"))
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Missing Authorization Header");

            User user = null;
            try 
            {
                var authHeader = AuthenticationHeaderValue.Parse(Request.Headers["Authorization"]);
                var credentialBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(authHeader.Parameter);
                var credentials = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(credentialBytes).Split(':');
                var username = credentials[0];
                var password = credentials[1];
                user = await _userService.Authenticate(username, password);
            } 
            catch 
            {
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Authorization Header");
            }

            if (user == null)
                return AuthenticateResult.Fail("Invalid Username or Password");

            var claims = new[] { 
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier, user.Id.ToString()),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.Username),
            };
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, Scheme.Name);
            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(principal, Scheme.Name);

            return AuthenticateResult.Success(ticket);
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine and does not have any problem. The only question I already have is after the first request I call `user = await _userService.Authenticate(username, password);` and check the database to see if username and password are valid. In web development after first authentication we keep a token in cookie so we don't need to check database again. I want to do similar thing to eleminate calling the Authenticate function so I need to know what is the proper way and the best practice for developing a Web API with persistent authentication.

Also as a test I tried to save the token inside the session for an authenticated user. But it seems `Context.Session.SetString("SystemToken",token);` does not save the the token when called inside `BasicAuthenticationHandler`.

Comment: You don't want cookies or sessions in an API. You also want to include an expiry in your token, otherwise a user that's disabled in or removed from your database can continue to use you API. API clients generally authenticate with a token, sent as a request header. They log in to obtain a token and send this with each successive request.

Comment: @CodeCaster  But my customer asked me to use basic authentication, so I don't have the option to use token.

Comment: Each request should be authenticated on Web API, do not keep session active.